# Why does my precompiled binary change in yocto?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake

I wanted to try to use the Liberica JDK provided by https://bell-sw.com/ in Yocto. I didn't see a recipe for it so I tried to create my own. It simply pulls down the 32 bit arm pre-compiled binaries and installs them. This is my `.bb` file.

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI += "\
         https://download.bell-sw.com/java/11.0.11+9/bellsoft-jdk11.0.11+9-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt-full.tar.gz \
         "
SRC_URI[sha1sum] = "973d357361fd2a9c328e37c93e6f546ee43ade5f"

S = "${WORKDIR}/jdk-11.0.11-full"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT  = "1"

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/usr/share/java/
        install -d ${D}/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11-bellsoft
        cp -r "${S}" ${D}/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11-bellsoft
}

FILES_${PN} += "/"

do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"
EXCLUDE_FROM_SHLIBS = "1"
```

This pulls it down and adds it to my image fine. However, when I flash the image and boot it up, the java binary segfaults. I thought this was weird so I manually downloaded the same exact tarball on the target with the same checksum and extracted it and that one worked just fine. I then `diff`ed the two binaries and noticed that some how they are different! Which makes me wonder if yocto/bitbake could be doing something to the precompiled binaries.

Doing an `ls -l` shows that the binaries are a different size as well. This made me check through the workspace to see if the file changed during extracting and it didn't.

```
# Checking the workspace where I install the binary has the correct size
ls -l tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/bellsoft-jdk/11.0.11-r0/image/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11-bellsoft/jdk-11.0.11-full/bin/java | awk '{print $5}'
8120
```

```
# Checking on the target where the image is installed has the incorrect size
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11-bellsoft/jdk-11.0.11-full/bin/java | awk '{print $5}'
9788
```

Does anyone know what might result in the binary changing?

Comment: I also noticed that the file in the rpm has the correct size. Just on the image it's different. Running this shows that the that java should be correct...

`rpm -qlvp ./tmp/deploy/rpm/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/bellsoft-jdk-11.0.11-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm`

Comment: Also interesting, is that on the image if I check what RPM thinks the size should be RPM thinks the size is correct. Even though it's still a different size than what's listed there.

`rpm -qlv bellsoft-jdk`

8120 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11-bellsoft/jdk-11.0.11-full/bin/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `image-prelink` task running during `do_image`. Prelink modifies the binaries in a list of directories, including `/usr/lib`, but not `/usr/share`. In newer versions of Yocto, prelink is not enabled by default, as it can sometimes cause issues and is not helpful for reproducible builds.

You can also disable it by removing `image-prelink` from `USER_CLASSES` in your `local.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what was causing this behavior. However, I randomly tried installing to `${D}${datadir}/jvm/jdk-11.0.11-bellsoft` and then it didn't get modified anymore.